# Joining strings in golang

Tags: go

why are the output of those codes different?

```
fmt.Println(Join([]string{"name=xxx", string(127)}, "&"))
```

> output
>       name=xxx&

```
fmt.Println(Join([]string{"name=xxx", "127"}, "&"))
```

> output
>       name=xxx&127

Any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string(127) means the character whose code is 127, it is not printable.
use [strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt)